# What's the difference between "minifyEnabled" and "useProguard" in the Android Plugin for Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, proguard

I see that the Android Plugin for Gradle has a `minifyEnabled` property as well as a `useProguard` property, as follows:

```groovy
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
        }
    }
}
```

What's the difference between these two properties? Or, rather, what's the meaning of each?

Comment: You could read about it here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking

Comment: That document (at the time of writing this comment) contains nothing about the `useProguard` property @cricket_007. Unless `useProguard` is a rename of the `shrinkResources` property in recent releases of the Android Plugin for Gradle?

Comment: "resource shrinking only works in conjunction with code shrinking (such as ProGuard)"

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Quoting from [tools.android.com](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/built-in-shrinker):

> **Built-in shrinker**
>
> Version 2.0 of Android Plugin for Gradle ships with an experimental
>   built-in code shrinker, which can be used instead of ProGuard. The
>   built-in shrinker supports fast incremental runs and is meant to speed
>   up iteration cycles. It can be enabled using the following code
>   snippet:
>
> ```
> android {
>     buildTypes {
>         debug {
>             minifyEnabled true
>             useProguard false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **The built-in shrinker can only remove dead code, it does not obfuscate or optimize. It can be configured using the same files as
>   ProGuard, but will ignore all flags related to obfuscation or
>   optimization.**
>
> Unlike ProGuard, we support using the built-in shrinker together with
>   Instant Run: depending on the project, it may significantly decrease
>   the initial build and install time. Any methods that become reachable
>   after a code change will appear as newly added to the program and
>   prevent an Instant Run hotswap.

Comment: Thanks so much @Mattia. This explains it. So `minifyEnabled` removes dead code but does not obfuscate or optimize.

Comment: Seems to directly contradict this answer which is saying that minify does obfuscate a bit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290023/obfuscation-in-android-studio

Comment: updated link to the documentation : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#gradle-shrinker

Comment: Updated developer link, https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#gradle-shrinker

Comment: So it's recommended to use `minifyEnabled true` in both debug and release? It works fine with Proguard enabled? What happens when we use `useProguard false`, while setting the proguard files? Proguard rules are ignored?

Answer (score 36):

You don't need `useProguard true` anymore.

Code shrinking with R8 is enabled by default when you set the `minifyEnabled` property to true.

When you build your project using Android Gradle plugin **3.4.0 or higher**, the plugin no longer uses ProGuard to perform compile-time code optimization. Instead, the plugin works with the R8 compiler to handle the tasks according to the [official document](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html).

Comment: tried this, but there was no clue whether its working it or not. The mapping.txt file also not generated.

Answer (score 22):

I set `minifyEnabled true` for my release buildType and it removed an entire enum which it thougt to be unused code i guess. This made my app crash due to a `NoSuchFieldException`. Took me 4 hours to find the reason for this crash. 0/10 can not recommend minifyEnabled.

Comment: it means you don't want minifyEnabled to be true?

Comment: I don't want my app to crash in production, that is correct

Comment: For anyone who is reading this and think that this is correct and good reason because of its number of upvotes, please learn to configure and do optimization properly.  Setting `minifyEnabled` to true is a good practice and not using it because your app is not working properly in release mode and can't locate where is the problem coming from is already a bad trait of Android developer. Please learn the basic, it is easy to exclude classes that is being remove or obfuscated in release build by specifying it in proguard rules files. You just have to add it.

Answer (score 8):

Just enable `minifyEnabled` will have code both optimized and obfuscated.
This is because `useProguard true` is default so no need to set it explicitly.

See also:
[Obfuscation in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290023/obfuscation-in-android-studio)