# Android studio proguard not working for library aar even if minifyenabled true

Tags: gradle, proguard, android-studio-2.1

I have a Gradle app with 1 library aar project and few flavours, I am trying to implement proguard for library project.

I have declared proguard-rules.pro file as well as proguard-library.pro file. I have minifyenabled true, useproguard true but Proguard does not seem to work. I am using Android studio 2.1.2 with a gradle wrapper 2.10.

I also followed steps from the link below but did not work, [Proguard ignores config file of library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983248/proguard-ignores-config-file-of-library/27052696#27052696)

Can someone help to get proguard to run for my library aar project.

Edited:
I am just testing if proguard works for debug or not, My gradle file is as below:

Edited debug code below:

```
defaultConfig {
     proguardFiles 'proguard-library.pro'
     consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
     ...
     ...
}

buildTypes{


debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        ....
        ...
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must receive some error messages, as your `build.gradle` contains a few errors. Specifically, you will need to remove the following lines:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
useProguard true
```

Unless it is just a copy&paste error, you normally specify the proguardFiles like this:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Comment: I removed those 2 lines, but proguard does not work, the below line is a copy paste error, proguard files were mentioned as indicated by you

Comment: I had some build errors, so took the android studio suggestions and added apply plugin: 'maven', I checed on someother answer on stackoverflow which says minifyEnable does  not obfuscate code. Please see link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007485/whats-the-difference-between-minifyenabled-and-useproguard-in-the-android-p