# minifyEnabled removing used assets

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

I have a directory within my assets folder with json for a database.

> assets/database/database_1/locations.json

When using `minifyEnabled true`, it's removing those assets as it doesn't think they're used.

How do I tell ProGuard that they're used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out `minifyEnabled true` does not remove any assets, it's only for code optimization and obfuscates the remaining classes.

The issue was I'm using Gson with my database models without `@SerializedName` and with the obfuscation it wouldn't be able to bind the values.

```
dataclass MyModel( val myName : String )
```

would turn into: (or something more obfuscated)

```
dataclass XYZ( val 123 : String )
```

And then Gson could not find the value "myName" to put the JSON.

To solve this, you have two solutions.

- Either add `@SerializedName` to each variable.
- Or if you don't care for obfuscation, such as with open source apps,
  you can disable that optimization by adding `useProguard false`.

Comment: Should be `@SerializedName` rather than `@SerializableName`. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

It is not ProGuard who is doing this kind of optimization. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#keep-resources. That being said, assets should not be affected, just resources.

Comment: I was testing this, and using `minifyEnabled true` makes the app crash due to a value being null. And if I add the flag `useProguard false`, the app works as expected.

Comment: `minifyEnabled true` and `useProguard false` uses internal experimental minification, instead of ProGuard. This disables optimization and obfuscation. See also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007485/whats-the-difference-between-minifyenabled-and-useproguard-in-the-android-p#37007689 Are you sure the asset is gone? Have you used APK Analyzer to check this? Also, does this happen on release builds, debug ones or both?

Comment: I realized what was the problem. It was null not because it didn't exist, but because I'm using Gson, and it couldn't find it by it's name.

Answer (score 0):

minifyEnabled=true removes all my gpx files stored in assets folder.
The same project rebuild with minifyEnabled=false keeps all the gpx-files
in the assets f

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).