# Signing for protecting the JAR from reverse-engineering

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, signature

I'm thinking how to protect the JAR from reverse-engineering.

**(Question 1):**

If JAR is signed by signature, is the signature able to protect the JAR? If not, then what is the purpose of signing?

**(Question 2):**

Android APK can be signed by platform signature, and It is impossible for extracting the platform signature from the APK itself.

From this point of view, I think signature can be used to protect something. But why can we decompile any APK even it is protected by platform signature?

Comment: 1. No. It protects somebody else from changing the contents of the jar and claiming it is legit.

Comment: Please check this https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Bytecode_obfuscation if you need to make it hard to reverse engineer your jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about your own signature, that you write with a pen. Does signing a piece of paper make the contents of the paper somehow impossible to read?

No: it simply gives somebody reading the paper an indication that it was written by you (or you agree with its contents, or whatever).

And so it is with signing a jar: all it does is gives people an indication that you (or people you have authorized to use the signature) produced it, in order that nobody else can change the jar contents and present it as "authentic".

Signatures will not help you to stop reverse engineering.

Comment: Thank you, @Andy Turner.

Answer (score 2):

> If JAR is signed by signature, is the signature able to protect the JAR? If not, then what is the purpose of signing?

If you *sign* a contract, does that prevent any of the involved parties from breaking the contract?! Nope, it doe not. The signature is simply something that (theoretically) legally identifies you.

And that is the whole point of *signing* software: to tell users of the software: "this is my delivery, you can trust it, because **I** signed it (and nobody else can have changed it)".

Signatures do **nothing** to protect your content from reverse engineering. They are solely useful for users of your content, as they can be "sure", that they are really using *your* content, and not something that a third party faked and only claims to be *your* delivery.

The only kind of protection is to look into **obfuscating** your JAR file content. There are tools for that (especially on Android). Nonetheless obfuscation for Java isn't exactly perfect. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290023/obfuscation-in-android-studio) for example.

Comment: @Global Kinda irrelevant. You asked about signing, and that part was answered. As said: the world of obfuscation in Java isn't straight forward, and also not perfect. But for that specific topic, there are plenty of questions around here already. So study those first. And please dont forget to accept one of the answers at some point.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I deleted my original comment because it contains one website link from outside that may not suitable for here. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

> If JAR is signed by signature, is the signature able to protect the JAR? If not, then what is the purpose of signing?

As the others have pointed out, it prevents others from distributing their own copies of your code under your name/brand. For example, suppose you write a calculator and post a signed bytecode on github, then I can't write my own bytecode and claim (without getting caught that its a false one, unless I find the key with which it was signed, which itself is very very ... very unlikely) that it is a copy of your calculator.

> But why can we decompile any APK even it is protected by platform signature?

Because, it does not prevent us from decompilation. We can get the source code from such APKs but, we cannot like put our own arbitrary code in its place and makes others believe it is same as yours.

**Put in plain terms, a signature is a proof of source and authenticity of a code, nothing more.**

Edit:

> Why can't we extract the original signature from the APK? Why is it impossible?

Because the signature is a hash, generated using a cryptographic hash function and a key that only you hold (called private key) and a public key, which is freely available. Since that private key is with you and assuming that you used a powerful cryptographic hash function, it will take a lot of time for a person trying to impersonate that key to find that key by directly trying all the hashes possible, which is usually the only possible way unless you have a clever work-around to find the key. The public key is openly available and is used for verification of the authenticity of the signature.

> Can we use this mechanism for protecting our JAR?

Depends on what you are trying to protect. If it is impersonation by somebody else, then yes, for sometime, as long as they do not stumble upon the key by some way. As seems for obvious, it is no good against reverse engineering

Comment: The point is: Why can't we extract the original signature from the APK? Why is it impossible? Can we use this mechanism for protecting our JAR?

Comment: I edited it include all that too. Hope you are answered, though I see Andy already did that:)

Comment: Thank you very much for detail explanation.